# Use http.client to login to the online Farasa lemmatizer and lemmatize arabic text file content

Tags: python, nlp, arabic, lemmatization

I am trying to use the code for Farasa lemmatizer into my code to lemmatize text files or csv files  that contain Arabic language. here is the link to the code http://alt.qcri.org/farasa/

I tried to just pass a text for the **payload** variable and it works.
My question  can I pass file  to the code on the website of farasa to start the process of lemmatization. I am trying to understand what is (payload) but I couldnot

Here is what I attempted

```
import http.client
from IPython.core import payload

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("farasa-api.qcri.org") 
payload = "{\"text\": \"يجب أن يرحلوا و يعودوا إلى الوطن هذا مثال بسيط\"}".encode("utf-8")

#the below line is not working 
#payload = "{\"file\":\"F:/AIenv/textAnalysis/testin2.txt\"}".encode("utf-8")

headers = { "content-type": "application/json", "cache-control": "no-cache", }

conn.request("POST", "/msa/webapi/lemma", payload, headers)

# conn.request("POST", "/msa/webapi/lemma", files = files, headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

does anyone have any idea about this problem and how can be fixed ?

Comment: You should try to read the file contents and send it as a string in the payload

Answer (score 0):

This is just an HTTP request.

You should be able to use a file.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection
Under HTTPConnection Objects in the documentation, you can find more details about what is the payload. It is the "body" part in the domentation.